# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch using collection_select, product expected, got String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, collections, associations

I am using collection_select in a form and I keep receiving an error where an object is expected but a String is received. How do I resolve this? Is there anything wrong with my collection_select syntax? I want a new LineItems object with a Color object available to the product to be passed to this new object. Below is my code and errors:

### products/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for LineItem.new do |f| %>
        <%= f.collection_select :color_id, @product.colors.all, :id, :name, { prompt: 'Select a Color' } %>
        <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :product, :value => @product %>
        <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

### controllers/line_items_controller.rb

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end
  def create
    @line_item = LineItem.create!(params[:line_item].merge(:cart => current_cart))
    flash[:notice] = "Added #{@product.name} to cart."
    redirect_to current_cart_url
  end
end
```

### models/line_item.rb

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :quantity, :unit_price, :product, :cart, :color_id, :color
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
  has_one :color
end
```

### migration

```
class CreateLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :line_items do |t|
      t.decimal :unit_price
      t.integer :product_id
      t.integer :cart_id
      t.integer :color_id
      t.integer :size_id
      t.integer :extra_id
      t.integer :quantity

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

## errors

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch at /line_items
Product(#40266200) expected, got String(#18896220)

ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation#raise_on_type_mismatch
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb, line 204
ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation#replace
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb, line 6
ActiveRecord::Associations::BelongsToAssociation#writer
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb, line 17
block in LineItem#order=
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb, line 51
block in LineItem#assign_attributes
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb, line 85
LineItem#assign_attributes
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb, line 78
LineItem#initialize
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/base.rb, line 498
LineItem.create!
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/validations.rb, line 39
LineItemsController#create
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb, line 6
```

Any help is fully appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the way you are trying to create a new line item. You are passing the `product` object through the hidden field in your view that will eventually convert to a string something like `#<Product:0xc412bdc>` when the html is rendered and hence it will be passed as a string when the form is submitted.

So, you may need to pass the `product_id` instead of `product` through the form like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :product_id, :value => @product.id %>
```

Now this should work.